# Preventing nested list output from a for-loop / list comprehension when appending new values to an Array

Tags: python, numpy, append, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I am trying to loop over a list comprehension where the output ('my_array') is being iterated over in the list comprehension:

```
my_array = np.linspace(1, 8, 10)
harmonic = np.random.rand(10,4)
var1 = (11, 12, 13, 14)
for coeff in range(4):
    my_array = [my_array + harmonic[coeff] * var1]
```

While this appears to work, my_list ends up being nested within 4 other lists and an array:

```
[array([[[[ val1, val2, ...]]]])]
```

I have two questions:

1. Can I accomplish the above without getting a deeply nested list as a result?
2. Should I just give up on the list comprehension and use two for loops instead (for the sake of improved readability)?

**UPDATE:** I wasn't being clear enough in my original post to convey the issue I've been having. The original code snippet is too simplistic for the actual case. `harmonic` is a 10x4 array in this example, `var1` is a 4 element tuple that has been yanked from a dictionary, and `my_array` (previously `my_list`) is a 10 element array. I would like to multiply the first column in `harmonic` with the first element in `var1`, the second column of `harmonic` with the second element of `var1`, and so on. I would then like to add these 4 columns and `my_array` together.

I used Pacific Stickler's solution 1 with a small variation, to account for the more complex variables:
`product = harmonic * var1`
`new_array = my_array + np.sum(product, axis=1)`

Comment: Try `my_list = my_list + [cycle[coeff] * var1]`?

Comment: or `my_list.extend([cycle[coeff] * var1])`

Comment: are `cycle` and `var1` arbitrary variables? or do you imply `itertools` function `cycle` here?

Comment: my apologies, cycle is not a function, it's a variable.

Comment: Can you state more clearly what you are trying to accomplish? Your question doesn't really have anything to do with list comprehensions, only basic list operations.

Comment: The name `my_list` is extremely confusing, since upon the first assignment, the variable's bound, **not** to a `list`, but rather to a `numpy.ndarray`.  So, first and foremost: **what** type of object do you want to be bound to `my_list` at the end?  Hint: if not to a `list`, _please_ rename that variable to something more sensible/less confusing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Confusion:**

Your problem statement seems unclear because of:

1. your mentioning of `list comprehension` but not using it
2. your usage of confusing / specialized names for variables in a toy problem which should have simple non-conflicting dummy names
3. absence of the desired output given some dummy values of the variables
4. unclear goal of either adding or concatenating the values to your existing array

**First, let's Get Your Problem Straight:**

You have:

1. a `numpy` array called `my_list`
2. a `list` called `harmonic`
3. a variable called `var1`

You want to either:

1. add to `my_list` element-wise the sum of the first 4 values of `harmonic` after each has been scaled by `var1` **OR**
2. append to `my_list` the first 4 values of `harmonic` after they have been scaled by `var1`

Assume dummy values for `harmonic` and `var1`:

```
harmonic = np.arange(4)
var1 = 2
```

**Solution:**

*For the 1st goal:*

You don't need to use either a `list comprehension` or a nested `for loop`:

1. you can multiply element-wise `var1` with `harmonic` and then use `np.sum()` to add all of its elements
2. you can then add element-wise the result from step `1` to `my_list`

Remember: scalar operations are always `element-wise` in `numpy`

```
>>> my_list + np.sum( harmonic * var1 )
array([ 13.        ,  13.77777778,  14.55555556,  15.33333333,
    16.11111111,  16.88888889,  17.66666667,  18.44444444,
    19.22222222,  20.        ])
```

*For the 2nd goal:*

1. You can again element-wise multiply `var1` with `harmonic` *OR* use `list comprehension` to loop over first 4 values of `harmonic` and form a new list of modified values.
2. Then use `np.append()` to concatenate the newly formed list to your `my_list`.

i.e.

```
>>> np.append( my_list, var1 * harmonic ) 
# equivalent to: np.append( my_list, [harmonic[i] * var1 for i in range(4)])
array([ 1.        ,  1.77777778,  2.55555556,  3.33333333,  4.11111111,
        4.88888889,  5.66666667,  6.44444444,  7.22222222,  8.        ,
        0.        ,  2.        ,  4.        ,  6.        ])
```

**Your Incorrect Approach:**

Your code tries to form a `list` using `list comprehension` by forming a new `numpy` array at each iteration by adding the modified elements of `harmonic` element-wise to your old `my_list` and concatenating this newly formed `numpy` array to your `list` at each iteration.

So your approach is equivalent to the following:

```
>>> my_list = [my_list + harmonic[i] * var1 for i in range(4)]
```

which offcourse gives you a (`nested`) `list` of `numpy` arrays:

```
[array([ 1.        ,  1.77777778,  2.55555556,  3.33333333,  4.11111111,
         4.88888889,  5.66666667,  6.44444444,  7.22222222,  8.        ]), array([  3.        ,   3.77777778,   4.55555556,   5.33333333,
         6.11111111,   6.88888889,   7.66666667,   8.44444444,
         9.22222222,  10.        ]), array([  5.        ,   5.77777778,   6.55555556,   7.33333333,
         8.11111111,   8.88888889,   9.66666667,  10.44444444,
        11.22222222,  12.        ]), array([  7.        ,   7.77777778,   8.55555556,   9.33333333,
        10.11111111,  10.88888889,  11.66666667,  12.44444444,
        13.22222222,  14.        ])]
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I edited my question to better reflect the variables I was dealing with, and then listed the solution I ended up using (your '1st goal' solution with slight modification).

Comment: Well, I'm glad it helped out.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you're not actually using a list comprehension in this code. You could, if you wanted. Try this instead:

```
my_list = range(10) + [cycle[coeff] * var1 for coeff in range(4)]
# in python3, you'll have to do ... = list(range(10)) + ...
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out that I wasn't using a list comprehension, and suggesting a way to get rid of the for loop all together. I'm running python 2.7, and when I run your code using ... = list(my_list) + ... I get a returned list with an incorrect length. When I don't use list(), and just use my_list = my_list + ... I end up with 4 separate lists inside a larger list. In the end, I can just add the lists together element-wise to get my desired solution, but is there a way to get a single list without this extra step?